# Save a drawed lines as Object

Tags: c#, line

is there any posibility to save something which i created with a graphics?
for example:

```
Graphics g = PanelOne.CreateGraphics();
g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
g.DrawLine(p, beginn, end);
```

Is it possible to save the whole line as an Object?

the reason is, that i need to program a very basic Drawtool, and this should have a "undo"-function. At the moment im saving the Point in a an array, and overdraw them white if the User presses the Backslashkey, but the performance is incredible slow, it judders.

Also i maybe want to add the possiblility to drag&drop lines, and this would be much easier if the lines are saved in an object.

Thanks in adavnce.

Comment: You can save points in a list. And use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that, but you should draw all the objects in the `Paint` method:

```
public abstract class DrawingObject
{
    public abstract void Draw(Graphics g);
}

public class Line : DrawingObject
{
    public Point Start { get; set; }
    public Point End { get; set; }
    public float Thickness { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }

    public override void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color, Thickness), Start, End);
    }
}

// Other classes derived from `DrawingObject`
```

In your form, store the list of your `DrawingObjects`s and draw them whenever needed:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    //...

    List<DrawingObject> _objects = new List<DrawingObject>();

    private void PanelOne_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        foreach (var o in _objects)
        {
            o.Draw(e.Graphics);
        }
    }
}
```

Call panel's `Invalidate()` method when any change happens to your objects (new line, remove a line, move a line, etc.).

To avoid flicker while drawing, you can set the [`DoubleBuffer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered.aspx) property of the panel to `true`.